# And Query on Parse Cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

this looks a very trivial query but I can't seem to make it work..
I am trying to get for instance an object that has locationName = "NYC" AND groupName = "Adults". I am trying to query using this code I found on Parse documentation:

```
    var groupQuery = new Parse.Query("MyTable");
    groupQuery.equalTo("group", groupName);
    var locationQuery = new Parse.Query("MyTable");
    locationQuery.equalTo("location", locationName);
    var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(locationQuery, groupQuery);
```

But I obviously fail because I am using Parse.Query.or instead what should have been Parse.Query.and which, for some reason doesn't exist...
Is there any alternative way to do it, for some reason I cannot find it on the documentation..
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Parse queries use and by default, which is why there is only a Parse.Query.or().
What you want to do can simply be achieved this way :

```
var mainQuery = new Parse.Query("MyTable");
mainQuery.equalTo("group", groupName);
mainQuery.equalTo("location", locationName);
```

Comment: Many thanks! This actually works! So if I need to do an "And" query from 3 different columns I'll just chain them same way one after another?

Comment: Odd implementation.. Would prefer something more similar to a classic SQL query style, but will have to work with what we got :)